# Javascript does not exit for loop when return statement is called

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, return, infinite-loop

While iterating through the `for` loop inside my function, even after the `return` statement is reached, the loop proceeds infinitely.

At this point, `j` is greater than `lister.length`. It exits the `for` loop and at the end of function jumps back to the `for` loop in a seemingly endless circuit.

This behaviour doesn't make sense to me as the `return` statement should terminate the function.

---

Here is my function:

```
function permutationLoop(originalArray, listOfPermutations) {

    // generates a permutation(Shuffle),and makes sure it is not already in the list of Perms
    var lister = generatingPerms(originalArray, listOfPermutations);

    //adds the permutation to the list
    listOfPermutations.push(lister);

    var tester = true;

    //This for loop looks through the new permutation to see if it is in-order.
    for (var j = 0; j < lister.length; j++) {

        //This if statement checks to see as we iterate if it is in order
        if (lister[j] > lister[j + 1]) {
            tester = false;
        }

        if (j == (lister.length - 1) && tester == true) {
            //Return the permutation number that found the ordered array.

            return listOfPermutations.length;
            //THIS IS NOT EXITING THE LOOP
        }

        if (j == lister.length - 1 && tester == false) {
            permutationLoop(originalArray, listOfPermutations);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input you're calling the function with (`generatingPerms` too, hopefully, because it's in the code you're using), ideally in a live snippet, so we can see how the function is running for ourselves and try to debug it?

Comment: What is `generatingPerms()`?

Comment: The problem is : `if (lister[j] > lister[j+1])`; if `j` is the last element, `j+1` will be undefined and thus less than the last element, so `tester` will be  set to false and the return-having IF's conditional's always false on the last element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may your if statement is not valid
try testing by `if(true){ ..code.. }`